# Can Tupper's self-referential formula plot any monochromatic image?

Tags: functions

Can Tupper's self-referential formula be used to plot *any* monochromatic image (an image containing only two colors) with arbitrary "quality" of the image? E.g., if we take a screenshot on a 5K iMac and make it monochromatic, will the formula be able to graph it?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [Self Referential Formula in Math](http://jtra.cz/stuff/essays/math-self-reference/index.html):

> Its graph contains all possible bitmaps that fit in region of 17 * 106 grid. So it is not much of wonder that one of those many bitmaps contains meaningful representation of the formula itself.

So, the formula actually generates a long mosaic of all the possible monochromatic (1 bit per pixel) 17 * 106 images. The image of the formula is one (actually many) of the subimages.

The formula can be very aptly described as a [Library of Babel](http://hyperdiscordia.crywalt.com/library_of_babel.html) generator.

A 5K screenshot is too big to fit, but the formula can be generalized to bigger sizes.

Comment: I understand that to generalize we have to replace '17' with some $n$, but where does 106 come from?

Comment: @Constantine, I don't know where is hidden the 106. Maybe the original article of Tupper can be illuminating: http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/mooncake/papers/SIGGRAPH2001_Tupper.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Tupper's self-referential formula (when suitably modified) can be absolutely used to plot any two coloured image of arbitrary height and width. Thus, indeed, you can take a screenshot on a 5K iMac and make it monochromatic and you will be able to graph it provided you have modified the formula suitably. The modifications have to do with the fact that the original formula was created for the pixelated image of the formula itself whereas you want it for your 5K screenshot. I have mentioned the specific steps needed to be followed for doing these modifications in another answer [How to generalize Tupper's self-referential formula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749330/how-to-generalize-tuppers-self-referential-formula)

For my convenience and your ease of reference, I will copy my answer from that question:
Suppose you have an image (two coloured bitmap) of arbitrary height and width and you want to find an inequality (that looks similar to Tupper's self referential formula) and the value of N for that image such that when you make a graph of that inequality with that particular value of N you get back your image. Then:

1. if the height of your image (i.e. the length along the vertical Y direction) is other than 17 pixels (say 45 pixels) then just replace the 17 in the original formula with 45. Also don't forget to do so in the range of y (i.e. the new range of y should be N < y < N + 45)
2. if the width of your image (i.e. the length along the horizontal X direction) is other than 106 pixels (say 192 pixels) the just replace 106 with 192 in the range of x (i.e. the new range of x should be 0 < x < 192)
3. if both width and height of image are other than 106 and 17 respectively then do both the replacements mentioned above.

Doing the above steps will give you the inequality (which will look identical to original formula if the height of your image is exactly 17 pixels) to be plotted and the exact range of x in which to plot it. However, the exact range of y is still not known as we don't know the value of N (since it depends on what your image is).
The method to find the value of N is well explained in the article https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/how-does-tuppers-self-referential-formula-work/ which also well explains how the formula works in general. Briefly, the method first finds the value of N in binary (i.e. in base 2) from the image and the converts it into decimal (i.e. base 10). To find the binary N from the image it involves traversing your image (bitmap) column wise i.e. going from down to up and then from left to right starting from the bottom-left corner of the image. The bottom-left corner maps to the rightmost bit in the binary N and so on. Whenever a pixel is black the bit corresponding to the pixel is set to 1 otherwise it is kept to 0.
Once all the above mentioned things are completed you will have an inequality which when graphed in the range of x and y that you had found, will give the image you had desired.

For better visualization, I have created a python script which is [available on github](https://github.com/PranayPallavTripathi/Tupper_related_codes/) and which allows you to draw any two coloured pixelated picture on a grid of height 17 pixels and width 106 pixels which then gives you the value of N corresponding to that picture so for example if you have the following picture
[image: playing cards suites pixelated]
then the value of N corresponding to this picture which I found using the above linked script is
573664048802431285558384669364352925059638745045637318771330283263689925623512983966825565546953441049160288866400662368999420358297824194432021809665303159472762426112693175725741721715844365367846948865802115889305652072084761535561585075425406795419160445636331380266234319267174478760508576590406346155428633201020192455643408277590918394462619142989337244768646480332610252190311941581014022074814334170654936502928583356066933856116345126839941691180729761792

If you plot Tupper's self referential formula on 0 < x < 106 and N < y < N + 17 with the above mentioned value of N, you will get the image displayed above.